# i want to append my each input name attribute with the counter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

my code is appending hidden div into another div on button click hidden div have a form i want on every button click name should have a counter value

```css
var i=0;
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#addNew").click(function() {
    i++;
    var maindiv=document.getElementById('nestedFeilds').innerHTML;
    $("#nestedFeilds :input").each(function() {
      var orignalname=$(this).attr('name');
      $(this).attr('name', orignalname + i);
    }
    );
    $("#showhere").append(maindiv);
  }
  );
}

);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row" id="mainContainer">
  <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-4">
    <label for="Education">Education</label>
  </div>
  <div class=class="col-md-8 col-xs-8  verticalLine" id="nestedFeilds" style=" margin-left: 10px ;float:left; display: none">
    <a href="" style="color: red;margin-left: auto; ">Delete Education</a>
    <input type="text" placeholder="School Name" class="form-control" id="School_Name" required="" name="School_Name[]"> |
    <br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Feild of Study" class="form-control" id="feild_Name" required="" name="feild_Name[]">
    <br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Degree" class="form-control" id="Degree_Name" required="" name="Degree_Name[]">
    <br>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row" id="2ndmainContainer">
  <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-4"></div>
  <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-8  verticalLine" id="showhere" style=" margin-left: 10px ;float:left;"></div>
  <div style="margin-left: 120px; float:left;"><a id="addNew"> Add Education</a></div>
</div>
</form>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-2">
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

now whats happening is i am getting such name attribute

```
School_Name_0
School_Name_01
School_Name_02
```

Comment: What is the desired attribute name? School_Name_0, School_Name_1, School_Name_2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the question is how to instead get School_Name_0, School_Name_1, School_Name_2, etc, just remove the last character of the string before adding your counter value:

```
$(this).attr('name', orignalname.substring(0, orignalname.length - 1) + i);
```

Comment: thankyou sir  it is working  sir can you tell me how to delete  any particular div